# what is difference between cdev_alloc and cdev_init

Tags: linux-device-driver

I'm creating a character device. I found two way to initialize char device

```
cdev_alloc
```

and

```
cdev_init
```

According to book, if i'm embedding `struct cdev` in my device struct then i should use `cdev_init`

Can any one tell me that what are difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

you can use either:

```
struct cdev my_cdev;
```

in this case you don't need to call cdev_alloc because memory is already allocated. Instead you must call `cdev_init(&my_cdev, &fops)`.
and then `my_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;`

OR

you can use:

```
struct cdev *my_cdev_p;
```

in this case you must call `cdev_alloc()` to allocate memory.
Then, you have to initialize `my_cdev_p->ops=&fops;` and `my_cdev_p->owner = THIS_MODULE;`. Never use `cdev_init()` in this case!

Note that the 2 above methods don't belong to the old mechanism.

Comment: why "never user `cdev_init()` in this case" ?

Answer (score 1):

According to linux device drivers 3rd edition .

cdev_alloc() is a older mechanism .this is used for getting cdev structure at runtime of your character driver module .then you have to manually assign operation to ops variable to cdev structure .However cdev_init is the new mechanism in this we have to pass cdev structure variable (or already initialized cdev structure pointer) and file operation variable,for information go here

http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

chapter 3

Comment: The problem is that when i use cdev_init alone then while clearning cdev using cdev_del i get error. I'm not able to track that error. on rmmod it just print killed. And using dmesg so far i'm able to get that it throw error

Comment: before cdev_del in your module did you add your char_dev after cdev_init() and you should also check return value of cdev_add .if possible show us the sample code .

Comment: link: http://kgcorner.com/car.c  I have used cdev_del in cleanup_module function, so cdev_init  and cdev_add have succefully workd. In given code just comment out cdev_alloc function and you'll get my problem

Comment: you can't use cdev_alloc() and cdev_init both at one cdev structure . just do one thing . remove cdev_alloc() and remove struct cdev* dev from that structure and use struct cdev dev1 variable  and pass that as cdev_init(&vcar->dev1,&file_op);

Comment: i don't think that putting cdev outside my struct would create a difference. Apart from that i'm not getting any problem when i'm using both of them together. I gues you didn't get my question correctly. The code i gave works correctly. But i'm confuse just because i'm not able to do all this with cdev_init alone.

Comment: hey I am not saying to put cdev outside your provate struct. instead that pointer use only a cdev structure not a cdev structure pointer . And I told you before also you can't use cdev_alloc and and cdev_init at one cdev structure they do the same thing.either use cdev_alloc or cdev_init

Comment: go here 
http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-4

and read carefully there about cdev_alloc() and cdev_init()

Comment: hi kripanand, I told i'm not able to use cdev_init alone, That's the problem. I understand as you are telling that both does same thing. But in mycase cdev_init alone does work correctly but cdev_del fails. cdev_del works only when i'm unsing both cdev_alloc with cdev_init and that's what my problem is. Why this absurd behaviour

Answer (score 0):

According to LDD3 for using cdev_init cdev should be initialized and shouldn't be NULL, so either use struct cdev dev as suggested by kripanand or if using struct cdev *dev then allocate dev memory using kzalloc, if using kmalloc memset would be required. This is wat cdev_alloc does.

I've now replaced cdev_alloc in my code as

```
//vcar->dev=cdev_alloc;
vcar->dev=kzalloc(sizeof(struct cdev),GFP_KERNEL);
```