# cdev_alloc() vs cdev_init()

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

In Linux kernel modules, two different approaches can be followed when creating a `struct cdev`, as suggested in [this site](https://lwn.net/Articles/195805/) and in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079376/2501622):

**First approach**, `cdev_alloc()`

```
struct cdev *my_dev;
...
static int __init example_module_init(void) {
    ...
    my_dev = cdev_alloc();
    if (my_dev != NULL) {
            my_dev->ops = &my_fops;  /* The file_operations structure */
            my_dev->owner = THIS_MODULE;
        }
        else
                ...
}
```

**Second approach**, `cdev_init()`

```
static struct cdev my_cdev;
...
static int __init example_module_init(void) {
        ...
        cdev_init(&my_cdev, my_fops);
        my_cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
        ...
}
```

(assuming that `my_fops` is a pointer to an initialized `struct file_operations`).

1. Is the first approach deprecated, or still in use?
2. Can `cdev_init()` be used also in the first approach, with `cdev_alloc()`? If no, why?

The second question is also in a comment in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079376/2501622).

Comment: If you called `cdev_init()` on the `struct cdev` allocated by `cdev_alloc()` you would get a nasty error message printed on the kernel log. Also the `cdev_put()` would not free the memory allocated by `cdev_alloc()`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Ok, but why would I get that error message? What does `cdev_init` that can not be done on a struct created with `cdev_alloc`? Then, maybe instead of `cdev_put` you meant `cdev_del`.

Comment: @BowPark: After the edit, in your first snippet `cdev_alloc` seems to be called **outside** of any **function**. This is prohibited in C language (unlike to C++). Moving call to `cdev_alloc` inside `example_module_init` looks more reasonable.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I actually only tried the second snippet, not the first (which I didn't know well). I'll fix this.

Comment: I meant moving inside the function only the call to `cdev_alloc`, not a **definition** of `my_dev` variable. With moved definition you cannot call `cdev_del` for that variable in the exit function.

Comment: @Tsyvarev My fault. Now I hope it's ok. If you can / if you would like to, please check out my comment to your answer.

Comment: You would get the error message to tell you that you have done something wrong. `cdev_alloc()` already partially initializes the `struct cdev` (but doesn't set the file operations like `cdev_init()`). Calling `cdev_init()` on the same `struct cdev` would wreck some stuff carefully set up by `cdev_alloc()`.

Comment: Yes, I meant `cdev_del()` not `cdev_put()` (`cdev_put()` and `cdev_get()` exist, but are only intended for use within "fs/char_dev.c" and are not exported.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can `cdev_init()` be used also in the first approach, with `cdev_alloc()`?

No, `cdev_init` shouldn't be used for a character device, allocated with `cdev_alloc`.

At some extent, `cdev_alloc` is equivalent to `kmalloc` plus `cdev_init`. So calling `cdev_init` for a character device, created with `cdev_alloc`, has no sense.

Moreover, a character device allocated with `cdev_alloc` contains a **hint** that the device should be **deallocated** when no longer be used. Calling `cdev_init` for that device will clear that hint, so you will get a **memory leakage**.

---

Selection between `cdev_init` and `cdev_alloc` depends on a **lifetime** you want a character device to have.

Usually, one wants lifetime of a character device to be the **same as** lifetime of the **module**. In that case:

1. Define a static or global variable of type `struct cdev`.
2. Create the character device in the module's **init** function using `cdev_init`.
3. Destroy the character device in the module's **exit** function using `cdev_del`.
4. Make sure that file operations for the character device have `.owner` field set to `THIS_MODULE`.

In complex cases, one wants to create a character device at specific point **after module's initializing**. E.g. a module could provide a driver for some hardware, and a character device should be bound with that hardware. In that case the character device cannot be created in the module's init function (because a hardware is not detected yet), and, more important, the character device cannot be destroyed in the module's exit function. In that case:

1. Define a field inside a structure, describing a hardware, of pointer type `struct cdev*`.
2. Create the character device with `cdev_alloc` in the function which creates (probes) a hardware.
3. Destroy the character device with `cdev_del` in the function which destroys (disconnects) a hardware.

In the first case `cdev_del` is called at the time, when the character device is **not used by a user**. This guarantee is provided by `THIS_MODULE` in the file operations: a module cannot be unloaded if a file, corresponded to the character device, is opened by a user.

In the second case there is no such guarantee (because `cdev_del` is called NOT in the module's exit function). So, at the time when `cdev_del` returns, a character device can be still in use by a user. And here `cdev_alloc` really matters: **deallocation** of the character device will be **deferred** until a user closes all file descriptors associated with the character device. Such behavior cannot be obtained without `cdev_alloc`.

Comment: This is clear, thank you, but now I'm confused about what is the best approach. My case is simple, with a single device, single minor number. Is `cdev_alloc` (and so dynamic allocation) preferable?

Comment: I have updated the answer about use cases for `cdev_init` and `cdev_alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

They do different things. The preference would be usual - prefer not to use dynamic allocation when not needed and allocate on stack when it's possible.

`cdev_alloc()` dynamically allocates `my_dev`, so it will call `kfree(pointer)` when `cdev_del()`.

`cdev_init()` will not free the pointer.

Most importantly, the lifetime of the structure `my_cdev` is different. In `cdev_init()` case `struct cdev my_cdev` is bound to the containing lexical scope, while `cdev_alloc()` returns dynamically allocate pointer valid up until free-d.

Comment: "and allocate on stack when it's possible." - I would hardly imagine cdev struct to be allocated on stack. Character device is created in one function (e.g. init) and destroyed in **another** one (e.g. exit); between invocations of these function the device is accessible to the user. So, if not dynamically allocated, cdev structure is usually a **global** variable or a **static** one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your considerations. I edited the question to give a more precise example. In fact, in the second case, the `struct cdev` is `static`.

Comment: @KamilCuk IIUC, it's preferable to use `cdev_init`. If I have a single device, is it really a problem if its memory area is not freed with `cdev_del`? You did not address the second question: can `cdev_init()` be used also with `cdev_alloc()`? If not, why?